# set param value in rails form_for method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I set the value of an attribute (called 'type') that I don't want to appear in a form? (i.e. I don't want the user to be able to select it in the form. I want to set the value myself).

My form code is:

```
<%= form_for @unit do |f| %>

     <%= f.datetime_select :start_datetime %>
     <%= f.text_field :notes %>

<% end %>
```

This generates params of:

```
{'unit' => {'start_datetime' => value, 'notes' => value }}
```

I want to set the 'type' attribute (to some value that I determine) so that the form returns params of:

```
{'unit' => {'type' => value, 'start_datetime' => value, 'notes' => value }}
```

Does form_for have some option that I can use to include 'type' in params and set its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it with **`hidden_field`** like this

```
<%= f.hidden_field :type,:value=>"some_value" %>

<%= form_for @unit do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :type, :value => "some_value" %>
  <%= f.datetime_select :start_datetime %>
  <%= f.text_field :notes %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @Pavan i beat you in answering first but you beat me by getting your answer accepted first :P

Comment: @user2675613 Yup! Your answer is also good :) I wanna give you +1.You deserve that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`hidden_field`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field) inside your form_for like:

```
<%= form_for @unit do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :type, :value => "your_value" %>
  <%= f.datetime_select :start_datetime %>
  <%= f.text_field :notes %>
<% end %>
```

which will give you params like:

```
{'unit' => {'type' => value, 'start_datetime' => value, 'notes' => value }}
```